# Accessing collection in view (MeteorJS + Angular)

Tags: angularjs, meteor, collections

I have data in a collection and I would like to access that information in my view (HTML file). I'm just a little unsure of how to approach it. I've looked online and didn't find much. The only way that I thought of was to maybe create some sort of function that would essentially copy the things in the database to an array, but I feel like there might be an easier method plus, it doesn't seem very reliable to me. Any ideas?

Code:

```
 Meals = new Mongo.Collection("meals-info");

 if (Meteor.isClient) {
   var myApp = angular.module('calorie-counter',['angular-meteor']);

   Meteor.subscribe('meals-info');


   myApp.controller('formCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {

   $scope.allMeals = $meteor.collection(Meals); //Not working for some reason

   $scope.meal = {
     item1: '',
     item2: '',
     createdBy: ''
   };
 }]);
}
```

Comment: Just put your collection in a scope variable. Please show us your code.

Comment: Just updated it. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.allMeals = $meteor.collection(Meals);` must be inside the controller and probably you have to inject `$meteor` too

Comment: Sorry, it was actually inside my controller but I messed up writing it up here. Um I get an error saying $meteor is not defined.

Comment: Okay, got it. Just had to modify my controller a bit